# eBPF Toolchain / compiling ebpf with CMake using clang and llc / two staged build process

Tags: c, cmake, clang, ebpf, llc

I have a bunch of ebpf-programs (using c and libbpf; no BCC/bpftrace) in a folder, let's call them `File1.bpf.c`, `File2.bpf.c`, `...`.
Usually, I compile bpf programs with `clang` and `llc`, every file by itself:

1. `clang -I  [...]/libbpf/build/root/usr/include/ -target bpf -S -D BPF_PROG -D __BPF_TRACING__ -D__TARGET_ARCH_x86 -Wall -O2 -emit-llvm -c -g File1.bpf.c`
2. `llc-11 -march=bpf -filetype=obj -o File1.bpf.o File1.bpf.ll`

With this, nothing is linked. I might want use bpftool to link **some** of the files afterwards.

So my questions are:

1. **How to do this two-staged build process in cmake?** I have seen some snippets using functions, but it did not work for me and feels very "hacky".
   Current idea is to use a python-script as a fake-Compiler. For cmake, the compiler is set to be the Python script, which invokes clang and llc. I think this is a possible solution, but it does not "feel right" and has problems, too. Additionally, I wonder why I can not find a Tutorial or a question on Stackoverflow about this topic, which leads to my second question:
2. **Is this procedure up to date?** If not: What is the preferred way to handle bpf compilation?

A visualization of the build process I want to achieve in cmake with every row being independent:
[image: Structure]

I do not want to use skeletons; the bpf objects should be independently loadable afterwards.

When looking online, usually in blogposts clang and llvm are used when it is c code.
However, it seems like clang can directly compile to a bpf object, which has the problem that `-mcpu` cannot be specified [1](https://qmonnet.github.io/whirl-offload/2020/04/12/llvm-ebpf-asm/). With `mcpu` the instruction set version is set. Therefore, another question is:

3. **When should `-mcpu` be specified?**

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I've tried to document a bit the `mcpu` parameter at https://pchaigno.github.io/bpf/2021/10/20/ebpf-instruction-sets.html. In most cases you should be fine with the default value for `mcpu`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @pchaigno; thats very good for understanding the `-mcpu` part. So it should be ok to just ignore that parameter und use clang only; however then I still hav to convince clang to not try linking anything. But better have it configurable? How do you compile your bpf programs?

Comment: In Cilium we use the two-step process, calling `clang` then `llc` from the Go process.

Comment: ok thanks! Interesting, tat not a common build system is used. Or is it a combination with make ([https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/master/bpf/Makefile.bpf](https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/master/bpf/Makefile.bpf))?